# How to enable shell_exec with open_basedir restriction for only one domain?

Tags: php, apache2, shell-exec, php-ini

I had disabled all dangerous php functions including `shell_exec` in my `php.ini`. Now I want to enable `shell_exec` only for a domain for executing only one command.How can I do it with `open_basedir` restriction or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to look on this like, i have search a little around for this.

hobe its help you.

http://discussion.accuwebhost.com/linux-server/1096-how-enable-shell_exec-function-one-account.html

Comment: Broken link. This answer should be updated or removed.